# How do I have ant list all failed jUnit tests?

Tags: ant, junit

I've seen a couple of posts about this but none provide the solution I'm looking for. I have ant set up so when it runs our tests we get the following output (which I like):

```
[junit] Running net.windward.document.test.TestTab
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.59 sec
[junit] Running net.windward.document.test.TestTableAttributes
[junit] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.604 sec
... continues for 300+ tests ...
```

But then at the end I just get "some tests failed". Is there some way to have it then list out the filenames of the tests that have failed?

thanks - dave

build.xml:

```
    <junit printsummary="yes" errorProperty="test.failed" failureProperty="test.failed" >
        <formatter type="plain" />
        <classpath path="${classpath.run.test}"/>

        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports}">
            <fileset dir="${src}">
                <include name="**/test/**/Test*.java" />
                <exclude name="**/_*/**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
    <fail if="test.failed" message="one or more unit tests failed"/>
    <echo>unit tests all passed</echo>

    <antcall target="testinternal"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read chapter 4 of "Java Development with Ant": http://www.manning-source.com/books/hatcher/hatcher_ch04.pdf

You can use

```
<formatter type="xml" />
```

to generate an xml output of the tests. This can be converted to html to view it in a browser after all tests have run using the ant task junitreport. You can also import the xml file into eclipse if you use it.

Comment: We tried that approach - it still lists all tests, not just the failed ones. In addition, we would prefer to get the listing in the console output - much faster to handle that way. Thanks - dave

Comment: Look at the bottom of http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html: using yet another formatter type "failure" should generate a Java TestCase with all failing tests that can be then re-run. Haven't tried it, though. Disadvantage is you must run failing tests twice.

Comment: You could try extending PlainJUnitResultFormatter and then writing only failing tests.